# Spring config server ssh git connection through proxy since boot 3.x is failing

Tags: spring, git, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, jgit

My team uses the spring config server to connect to a git repository that has most of our services configuration.
We decided to upgrade our config server to Spring boot from 2.7.2 to 3.1.0 and we also changed the spring cloud version to 2022.0.2

It appears after this change, the config server cannot reach out our github repository :

```
exceptionCaught(JGitClientSession[git@proxy-internet.org/10.X.X.X:XXXX])[state=Opened] NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentProperties.getPrivateKey()" because "sshProperties" is null
```

I don't get why it is connecting to the proxy through git. In my opinion, it should go to git@github.com/myOrg/myConfigRepo

Have you already encounter such an issue ? Is there something important that has changed in terme in configuration when switching to boot 3 and cloud 2022.X.X ?

Thank you for your time